# Can you refresh a SESSION when refreshing a page? AND HOW?

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to know how to refresh a page using AJAX, without having to *reload* it (F5, reload button, etc).

In my session (when I'm logged in), I upload and store a picture in my database. Every time I change my profile picture I have to log out and log in to view it. How can I refresh the page so it shows my new picture without having to reload the entire document?

Comment: You are wanting to refresh downloaded content, right (ie, a cached image)? Not a "session"?

Comment: While what you want to do here is definitely possible, this question is *way* too general. You need to show use some of your code - start by explaining why it is the session (assuming you mean `$_SESSION`) that affects this - are you storing the profile picture in the session when the login happens? In which case, all you need to do is update the session data when a new picture is uploaded... If @JaredFarrish is correct, take a look at the examples on the manual page for [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: After the image is uploaded I want the page to refresh without logging out and logging in again to see it! And I'm in a $_SESSION when the image is uploaded.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I'm glad to know it's possible! :P and lets say I want it to refresh every 10 seconds or so? How will that code look like?

Comment: @Joemeister How are you determining which picture should be loaded? Are you storing the path in `$_SESSION` or somthing else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your login code does something like:

```
$_SESSION['avatarurl'] = '/some/path/pic.jpg';
```

and that's the ONLY place where you set this session value. You would have to modify your "upload a new avatar" code to reset that value to the NEW url:

```
$_SESSION['avatarurl'] = '/some/path/newpic.jpg';
```

which would take effect on next page refresh, WITHOUT having to do a full logout/login cycle.

The browser will display whatever image you tell it to. If it's not changing the picture after you've uploaded a new copy, it's because you code has not made the necessary changes to tell the browser that something new is available.